# Inline Redirect in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

We're in the process of updating an MVC application. Currently, we cannot change any of the backend code and need to do an inline redirect on the razor page. How can I do a redirect to a URL directly in a razor page?

Comment: By "inline redirect", do you mean you want to route the URL to a specific view? If not, what do you mean by this? A redirect normally means to send a 302 or 301 status code to the browser and have it go elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use the [`Redirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680582(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
@{ 
    Response.Redirect("http://google.com");
}
```

or if you wanted to redirect to a controller action in the same application:

```
@{ 
    Response.Redirect(Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController"));
}
```

This will perform the redirect on the server by returning the 302 status code. If you want to make the redirect on the client you could either use the meta tag in the head section of the DOM:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://google.com">
```

or plain javascript:

```
<script>
    window.location = 'http://google.com';
</script>
```